# Check if HtmlString is whitespace in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, string, whitespace

I've got a wrapper that adds a header to a field whenever it has a value. The field is actually a string which holds HTML from a tinymce textbox.

**Requirement**: the header should not display when the field is empty or just whitespace.

**Issue**: whitespace in html is rendered as `<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>`, so technically it's not an empty or whitespace value

I simply can't `!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ContentField.Value)` because it does have a value, albeit whitespace html.

I've tried to convert the value onto `@Html.Raw(Model.ContentField.Value)` but it's of a type *HtmlString*, so I can't use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: FYI, `Html.Raw` merely makes it so the string will not be HTML encoded when rendered to the page. You'd still have all the actual tags and such in it even if you could compare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), something like this:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(Model.ContentField.Value);
string textValue = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(document.DocumentNode.InnerText);
bool isEmpty = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textValue);
```

Comment: Thanks. Good answer but I forgot to note that I'd prefer not to rely on third party libraries. If there were stuff built in mvc or httputility, that would be best.

Comment: I checked the code with the text given above in the question. Its doesn't works. HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
            string textValue = "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>";
            bool isEmpty = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textValue);

Comment: @Thanigainathan you forgot the loading and getting of innertext. From yours, it should be: document.LoadHtml(textValue); string innerValue = document.DocumentNode.InnerText; then compare the innerValue if null or whitespace.

Comment: @Thanigainathan, you were right. That was a quick post, right out of head. Now it was tested, updated with `HtmlEntity.DeEntitize`, and works correctly.

Answer (score 5):

What I eventually did (because I didn't want to add a 3rd party library just for this), is to add a function in a helper class that strips HTML tags:

```
const string HTML_TAG_PATTERN = "<.*?>";

public static string StripHTML(string inputString)
{
    return Regex.Replace
    (inputString, HTML_TAG_PATTERN, string.Empty);
}
```

After which, I combined that with `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` to get the inner value:

```
var innerContent = StringHelper.StripHTML(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.ContentField.Value));
```

That variable is what I used to compare. Let me know if this is a bad idea.

Thanks!

Comment: This should work too, unless TinyMCE uses invisible tags like `<comment>text</comment>` or `<script type="text/plain">text</script>`. Then again, I'm not sure if `HtmlAgilityPack` handles these correctly, either.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar question as your title, but in my case the html string was empty. So I ended up doing the following:

```
HtmlString someString = new HtmlString("");
string.IsNullOrEmpty(someString.ToString());
```

Might be obvious, but didn't realize it at first.

Comment: Not ok since new HtmlString("<b></b>").ToString() still returns a non emtpy string, which is not what OP wants.