# check if html contains tags and whitespaces

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I want to check if html string only contain white spaces. I used HtmlAgilityPack as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593413/check-if-htmlstring-is-whitespace-in-c-sharp), it works fine when html string only has text in it like:

```
 "< title></title><p style=\"margin: 0em 0px;\"><\br></p>"
```

but when it contains any tags like image, then HtmlAgilityPack  will also mark it as empty

```
 "< title></title><p style="margin: 0em 0px;"><img src="https: //www.google.com.pk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"></p><p style="margin:0em 0px;"><\br></p>"
```

I want to check that after rendering html data on browser it should not be an empty space.

Comment: Your html is invalid, also we need the code that you use for this validation to give you a good answer what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Are you looking to do this in C# or JS? Your tags make this confusing.

Comment: What are all those backslashes? Typos? You have a tag for HtmlAgilityPack which would suggest you try this in C#, not JQuery. Please clean up your tags to include only relevant ones and post some of your parsing code.

Comment: Tell us what exactly constitutes "text" & what "tag" for you. What do you consider a `<br/>` tag? What an `<hr/>`? Also: what you posted is *not* HTML. It is completely invalid. For *any* parser...  Maybe checking `[node].HasChildNodes` could suffice as a tag check?

Comment: Your `<br/>` tag is still wrong. You should probably learn a little more about HTML before trying to manipulate it. Also: still not comprehending your `blank space` comment. And you still haven't posted any of your code. That said, you could use something like the following snippet to determine whether a node contains an `<img...` tag: `if([yournode].ChildNodes.Any(c=>c.Name=="img"))`